# Utf-8 does not work in php file

Tags: html, character-encoding

I use notepad++ for coding.

I have a test.php file which is encoded with UTF-8 without boom. I have set the charset in the head as

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

However, if I open the file in a browser special characters like "äüö" are not represented correctly. If I go to pageinformation in firefox I get

```
Coding: windwos-1252
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Why is the coding wrong? How can I change it?

Comment: How are you serving the file ? Maybe your webserver is setting the content-type in the response header and firefox use this instead of what is in the HTML file ?

Comment: @krtek I just noticed that it does work correctly in IE 8 and Chrome, but it does not work in Firefox. Also - if I call the file directly it also works in firefox. But the page is called from another page (also coded as UTF-8 without boom) by a action form.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Because it looks like server configuation issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use notepad.exe which comes with windows and click SAVE AS option and change encoding there to utf-8 instead of ANSI. Save it and check.

I had similar issues.

Hope this helped

Comment: I tried this - but it didnt work. File was already saved as utf-8.

Answer (score -1):

what about utf-8 without bom?

It happens with certain text editors. Try notepad++ or similar ones.

Comment: I use utf-8 without bom and I also use notepad++. Both was mentioned in OP